# Replacing keypad period with comma in an input (type=number) with an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace, angularjs-directive, numeric-input

**Problem:**

I've been recently requested the feature of having the keypad period be replaced with a comma when inserting a number in a field in my spa application built with angular.
I decided to go with the directive approach to be able to easily reuse it in the future and had a partial success with it, but it works only on

```
input type="text"
```

When trying the same solution on

```
input type="number"
```

the field get reset and I get the following error:

> ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js:3501 The specified value "12," is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

but when I type, for example, `12,` no error is raised.

*Any idea on why and how to get it to work on number input?*

**Code:**

```
'use strict';

myApp.directive('replaceKeypadComma', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.on('keydown', function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 110) {
                    element.val(element.val() + ',');
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Working Plunker with text input:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/hBThZOI1T4rk3cbwRscq

**Broken Plunker with number input:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/zBqwWmZ0iAhIH728ZeCh

Comment: Your plnkr works as expected for me, using both chrome 60.0.3112.90, and Firefox 54.0.1...

Comment: The working plunker refers to text input.
Here a plunker referring to a number input, not working as intended: https://plnkr.co/edit/zBqwWmZ0iAhIH728ZeCh

Answer (score 1):

`input type="number"` is allowed to contain only a "[floating point number](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/input.number.html#input.number)" so [doesn't allow commas](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/datatypes.html#common.data.float).

[Some browsers](https://ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization) do accept input containing a decimal comma and transform it into a decimal period, depending on the user's or page's locale, but enough of them don't do this that it's probably best to avoid `input type="number"` if you need to support decimal-comma numbers.